# "I have no wish to fight. Here, take my cargo"

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I'm playing Litcube Universe (X3 mod) with Mayhem installed. I've started as Yaki, and now I'm -4 with everyone but Teladi, Yaki and Argons. I'm trying to rob the borons of their energy since there is nothing I can do for now to collect enough money... And they usually say what I've said in the title. But they don't drop anything, they just continue to crawl towards the gate, crippled and poor. So the question is, how do I force people to drop their cargo in Mayhem/Litcube's Universe?

Comment: It seems that only energy transporters act like that. Ore transporters and weapon transpoters drop their cargo.